# How can I detect if a viewController is no longer in the moreNavigationController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController that has extra views in the moreNavigationController. I would like to be able to detect when the user has clicked Edit, and moves a view outside of moreNavigationController onto the regular UITabBarController items. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please do not tag questions as “cocoa” that do not have anything to do with Cocoa. This question is specific to Cocoa Touch.

Answer (score 1):

A UITabBarController's behaviour can be fine-grained by giving it a delegate object which conforms to the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol.

You can do this either via code or with Interface Builder. If you've set up a custom `UIApplicationDelegate`, you know what you're looking for.

Once you've done that, implement the `tabBarController:didEndCustomizingViewControllers:changed:` method in your delegate. This method will be called **after** the customization pane has been dismissed and you can handle all your necessary logic within.

Read the ADC Documentation for [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [UITabBarControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController:didEndCustomizingViewControllers:changed:) for more information.